# disable other key listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to right simple `javascript` chrome extension that disables the key listeners in the webpage.

for example, when I am in `youtube` and pressing "l" the video is moving forward. I want some simple code that stops it and allows me to create my own key listener.

Can I do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent the default behaviour of the keypress, and then check the `event.keyCode` to do custom functions:

`$(document).on('keypress', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Check for the 'l' keycode
    if (event.keyCode == 108) {
      // Do what you want here!
    }
});`

This will prevent you from typing in comments and hitting spacebar to pause the video, etc.